# Visual Studio 2022 TFVC

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, visual-studio-2022, tfvc

I have switched computers and copied my VS project folder to my new computer.  Now, I am having trouble getting my Visual Studio TFVC working.

If I click the File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control menuitem it shows that my bindings are valid.

However, in Visual Studio when I click Pending Changes it wants to Add most of the files in my project.  For the files it doesn't want to add they have a red check mark in Solution Explorer indicating the files are different than what is in Source Control.

Does anyone know how I can get my local files to sync up with my files in Source Control?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the repetition of a tag that shouldn't be in the title and the words *Source Control*, which doesn't say anything. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it's about.

Comment: _"Does anyone know how I can get my local files to sync up with my files in Source Control?"_ - You should make a new local (or server?) workspace and do a clean checkout instead of copying+pasting your files over between machines. (Also, is there a reason you're not using `git` yet?)

Comment: Hi @Karl, have you checked the suggestion below? Does it work for you? If it's helpful for you, to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept the answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shelveset for the pending changes in the old machine, then connect to TFS from the new machine and map to a new workspace, then find the shelveset and unshelve, all the pending changes will be back to your new workspace. See the detailed steps from [Move TFS workspace to new machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496845/move-tfs-workspace-to-new-machine).